# How to define a more aggressive timeout for HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, async-await, portable-class-library

Inside a Portable Class Library, I've the following method which post data to a specific Url. The method works great. However I'd like to specify a more aggressive timeout (the default is 100 seconds).

Considering that there's no Timeout property on the HttpWebRequest class from the Portable Class Library, how can I make sure that the call is abandoned if it takes longer than a few seconds?

```
public async Task<HttpResponse> PostAsync(Uri uri, string data)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    using (Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
    {
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    }

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
    return new HttpResponse(response.StatusCode, await new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEndAsync());
}
```

Comment: HttpWebRequest.Timeout = 20000; ? this is smart enough?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Below code either will return a HttpWebResponse or null if timed out.

```
HttpWebResponse response = await TaskWithTimeout(request.GetResponseAsync(), 100);
if(response != null)
{
  ....
}
```

---

```
Task<HttpWebResponse> TaskWithTimeout(Task<WebResponse> task, int duration)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        bool b = task.Wait(duration);
        if (b) return (HttpWebResponse)task.Result;
        return null;
    });
}
```

**--EDIT--**

Creating an extension method would be even better

```
public static class SOExtensions
{
    public static Task<T> WithTimeout<T>(this Task<T> task, int duration)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            bool b = task.Wait(duration);
            if (b) return task.Result;
            return default(T);
        });
    }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync().WithTimeout(1000);
```

**--EDIT 2--**

Another way of doing it

```
public async static Task<T> WithTimeout<T>(this Task<T> task, int duration)
{
    var retTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(duration))
                            .ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (retTask is Task<T>) return task.Result;
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: Wow! Interesting idea! I like it since it is elegant and relatively easy to understand. But I wonder if task.Wait is a blocking operation (i.e. a thread is going to be put on hold until it returns).

Comment: @Martin Yes it is a blocking operation, but it is performed in another task(see : `Task.Factory.StartNew`) and will not be different than invoking  `await request.GetResponseAsync()`

Comment: I agree! It's just one more threads on the ThreadPool. I wonder if we could make it non-blocking. Blocking or not, this is a very clever solution.

Comment: This is a VERY BAD idea for two reasons. 
1. It uses a thread for every call. If you have 1000 calls made in parallel you will have 1000 threads in wait state. I personally drove a system to the ground with this technique.
2. When the operation "times out" the Web Request and the underlying TCP connection remains open forever. I personally drove another system down :) using exactly this technique.

Comment: @Alon-Catz 1. It uses a TASK for every call. Tasks aren't threads. TPL will try to devide the tasks over an optimal number of threads for the system that's being used. 2. I agree that the WebResponse needs to be disposed properly. That doesn't mean this is a bad solution. Just add a using statement: `using(var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync().WithTimeout(1000)) { }`

Comment: You are welcome to try it out and post the results here. My lessons were learnt the hard way. I just wanted to share.

Comment: Third part is the easiest to understand, makes more sense.

Comment: @Jop @Alon Disposing of the response properly doesn't seem to resolve the "TCP connection remains open forever" behavior that I also have seen.  In my experience you have to call `request.Abort()`.  Maybe reading to the end of the async response stream will have the same effect - I don't know right now.  Is this sufficient for addressing Alon's 2nd point though?  If I don't abort the request, even after success, I end up with a `Task` that just sits with a `Status` of `WaitingForActivation`, even on brand new instances of `HttpWebRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Abort the request if the timer fires. 
private static void TimeoutCallback(object state, bool timedOut) { 
    if (timedOut) {
        HttpWebRequest request = state as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request != null) {
              request.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Yes it is the responsibility of the client application to implement its own time-out mechanism. You can do this from the code above which sets the timeout and uses the ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject method. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.abort.aspx for the full details. Essentially it does an abort from GetResponse, BeginGetResponse, EndGetResponse, GetRequestStream, BeginGetRequestStream, or EndGetRequestStream.