# How to avoid thread waiting in the following or similar scenarios (want to make a thread wait iff its really really necessary)?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Please see the below code snippet. I am trying to execute a long running task, but i dont want to wait it for more than given timeout. I want to have full control on when the task starts, so spawning a new thread and doing the work, and simply waiting for it in parent thread. The pattern really works, but the parent thread is simply waiting. Ideally, i dont like thread to sleep/wait un-less its really needed to. How can i achieve this? any suggestions/thoughts/patterns are welcome.

```
/// <summary>
/// tries to execute a long running task
/// if the task is not completed in specified time, its deemed un-sccessful.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="timeout"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
bool Task(int timeout)
{
    bool workCompletedSuccessfully = false;
    //I am intentionally spawning thread as i want to have control when the thread start
    //so not using thread pool threads.
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        //executes some long running task
        //handles all the error conditions
        //ExecuteTask();
        workCompletedSuccessfully = true;
    });
    t.Start();
    //cannot wait more "timeout"                        
    //My main thread (parent) thread simply waiting for the spawened thread to join
    //HOW CAN I AVOID THIS?ANY PATTERN TO AVOID THIS REALLY HELPS?
    t.Join(timeout);
    if (!workCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        //deeemed un-successful
        //do the remediation by gracefully disposing the thread
        //itnentionally hidden details about disposing thread etc, to concentrate on 
        //the question - AVOIDING PARENT THREAD TO WAIT
    }
    return workCompletedSuccessfully;
}
```

Regards,
Dreamer

Comment: How, exactly, do you hope to **gracefully** dispose of a thread that hasn't completed its work yet?

Comment: Anyway, I'm not sure you can have your parent thread do something meaningful and also receive a timeout notification in any straightforward way. (That is, without making the parent thread work through an event loop that can receive either "task successful" or "task timed out" events.) Since, well, how would that work? Should the parent thread just be interrupted from whatever it was doing and handle the notification?

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838088/how-to-define-a-more-aggressive-timeout-for-httpwebrequest

Comment: @I4V Great idea, but it would obviously require "asyncifying" the whole codebase. (A nontrivial change, but probably the right call here.)

Comment: @millimoose yes it requries switching to TPL library but async/await is not a must.

Comment: @I4V That's what I meant really. One way or another it's a significant restructuring of your code to use asynchronous tasks that may return either success or failure.

Comment: If you don't want the parent to wait, why call t.Join(timeout)?  If your answer is "Because the  parent has to wait for the task to complete before it can continue" then that by definition means the parent has to wait.

Answer (score 2):

Use [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx).

```
bool Task(int timeout)
{
    AutoResetEvent threadFinished = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    //I am intentionally spawning thread as i want to have control when the thread start
    //so not using thread pool threads.
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        //executes some long running task
        //handles all the error conditions
        //ExecuteTask();
        threadFinished.Set();
    });
    t.Start();
    //Param - timeout
    bool finished = threadFinished.WaitOne(timeout);
    if (!finished)
    {
        //deeemed un-successful
        //do the remediation by gracefully disposing the thread
    }
    return finished;
}
```

The only problem I see here is what you plan to do with thread that didn't finish on time. Theoretically you can call `Thread.Abort()` but it is not good idea, because it can corrupt state of application.

**Edit**: You need to understand that `threadFinished.WaitOne(timeout);` is still blocking, but not longer then `timeout`.

Comment: I think what the OP wanted was to get rid of the parent thread waiting - I.e. having it go about its business but also be notified that the timeout occured.

Comment: @millimoose maybe. Let's see what he says.

Comment: @millimoose if that is what he really wants, he can just wrap my code into thread and launch.

Comment: Hi Andrey, thanks for quick response. But even, threadFinished.waitone(timeout) blocks the parent thread. Isnt it? Its just variant of the same pattern and using events rather than thread.join(). In other words want to avoid thread.join() or event.waitone() as the parent thread simply waits doing nothing. Regards, Dreamer

Comment: @Dreamer yes, it is blocking. To make it non blocking, just run my code in one more thread. So you will have 3 threads, the UI thread, the watcher thread and the worker thread.

Comment: @Andrey, with the introduction of new thread another thread will be waiting for notifications. i dont want any thread to wait unless its really needed here.  With your suggestion, you are simply spawning a new thread just to listent to event notification and responding them. the new thread simply waits. in other words, as millimoose metnioned i want to get rid of thread wait.

Comment: @Dreamer I'm afraid that's simply impossible. There really isn't a way to gracefully interrupt a thread from whatever it's doing and have it do something else for a while. (C signal handlers come to mind, and they're certainly not a concurrency mechanism.) You have to handle this explicitly somehow.

Comment: @Dreamer the question is how you want to handle it. what exactly you want to do? So the idea is that UI thread spawns watcher thread and doesn't wait for it. Watcher thread spawns worker thread, and blocks until its done or timeout expired. So there you can execute your handling code.

Comment: i want to know is there any patterns/recommended approaches to avoid thread wait un-less its really really needed. as metnioned, the approach in the question works, and am not blocked. i am just trying to see is there any better approach.

Comment: @Dreamer actually I can't fully understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This answer helped me solve a different problem unrelated to the question. Thanks!