# How to know if a thread is alive and then kill it?

Tags: multithreading, kill

I've been searching and reading about killing threads (C posix threads), and everybody says that is not a good idea because a thread should make its work and then return... but my problem is the next:

I'm reciving messages in my local network (using the recvfrom function), but this function "blocks" my program, I mean, if I don't revice any messege the function keeps locked (forever) until it recives something.

To avoid this, I thought to use threads, so, while my main thread is "counting", my second thread is try to recive messages. If in a determinated time (i.e. 1 second), my second thread is still waiting for a message (is locked in the recvfrom function) I need to "kill it" and then create another thread to start again (and try to recive messages from another IP). This means that not always my thread going to finish its work and I can't wait forever...

So far I can do that (create a lot of threads and recive the messages from the IP I'm interested in), but I don't know how to kill the threads that never recived anything...

Someone knows how to kill the threads? Or they are killed automatically when my main program returns?

Thank you and really sorry for my poor english...

Comment: Do a search for [non blocking sockets](https://www.google.com/search?q=non+blocking+sockets).

Comment: More specifically, select() with a timeout. It would help knowing what your program does though, in particular why you are trying different IPs in turn and not in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its related to one of my questions [How to avoid thread waiting in the following or similar scenarios (want to make a thread wait iff its really really necessary)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317468/how-to-avoid-thread-waiting-in-the-following-or-similar-scenarios-want-to-make)

But its .net, though (code sample is in C#)

Essentially i spawned new thread and performing some i/o oeprations and its a blocking call.

And for some reason it just waits foreve, i do have timeout so that i can abort the thread 'abort' method.

Answer (score 0):

Rearchitect so the thread can receive messages from *any* IP. That way, you can try to receive messages from another IP without having to disturb the thread.