# how to set httpclient connect timeout?

Tags: c#, timeout, httpclient

I'm struggling with setting connect timeout with c# `HttpClient` or its siblings (`HttpClientHandler`,`WebRequestHandler`,...) . There's a timeout property in `HttpClient`, but it seems to be a timeout from the beginning of the request until receiving the response. I want to have a method which specify that for example if you don't received ACK from the net socket within 10 seconds for example , then break up and do the next.
I saw that there may be something similar in `WinHttpHandler` class, but it seems to be deleted or not available in recent version. compare the first link vs second :

1.[WinHttpHandler MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.winhttphandler.connecttimeout(v=vs.105).aspx#P:System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.ConnectTimeout)

2.[WinHttpHandler Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.winhttphandler?view=netcore-2.0)

I really need this, because I must differentiate asap between IP's which have a working web servers (maybe slow) vs which don't have a web server at all.

Comment: Have you tried to use *TcpClient* or *Socket* and connect to *IP:Port* (since you said *Web Server* not *Web Site*)

Comment: I'm going to do my task with lowest overhead. I'm not going to wait for waiting for webserver or web site for some time,and if it was ok, then send some request and wait some time. There must be a way to this. I don't know who write this httpclient class, But I think he did not considered small important requirements of developers @L.B. HttpClient in Apache (java) have this property!

Comment: @Darrel Miller I think this great dude is behind the scenes of HttpClient. But don't know why he didn't designed it like this

Comment: But you haven't answer my question

Comment: @L.B No. I have not tried. You are right. I can do this, but this is not my solution because I make hundreds of request per second, and this approach somehow doubles it.

Comment: Maybe you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838088/how-to-define-a-more-aggressive-timeout-for-httpwebrequest

Comment: @L.B It must be implemented at low levels. at socket levels! With above approach, you always wait x seconds, not considering presence of webservice, network speed and delays and ....

Comment: `With above approach, you always wait x seconds,` No, *max* x seconds..

Answer (score 0):

I use `HttpWebRequest.Timeout` in my project to verdict the connection time before establish tcp connection. And use `HttpWebRequest.ReadOrWriteTimeout` to verdict whole response timeout.
Ps: The `HttpClient` seems cut off some useful properties.