# Owin self hosting - limiting maximum time for request

Tags: c#, owin

How to efficiently limit request length timeout on server side ? I'm using `Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener` and there are cases when (due to call to external service) serving request takes ridiculous amount of time. This is not a problem - but web server should give up sooner than - well never (I did some tests, but after 5 minutes I stopped it).

Is there a way how to limit time for serving single request (similar to `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="..." />` in IIS ecosystem) ?

Sample controller code:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get() {
  // ... calls to 3pty services here
   await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
}
```

Starting web server:

```
WebApp.Start(this.listeningAddress, new Action<IAppBuilder>(this.Build));
```

Note: I've read about limiting http listener, but that just limits incoming request properties, it doesn't cancel request that is slow due to slow server processing:

```
var listener = appBuilder.Properties[typeof(OwinHttpListener).FullName] as OwinHttpListener;
var timeoutManager = listener.Listener.TimeoutManager;
timeoutManager.DrainEntityBody = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
timeoutManager.EntityBody = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
timeoutManager.HeaderWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
timeoutManager.IdleConnection = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
timeoutManager.RequestQueue = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
```

Related:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/152

Comment: How about canceling your job taking so much time instead of delegating it to http listener.

Comment: Can you show us more code...we are not wizards, I mean, maybe we look like, but...

Comment: @Eser - I generally sympathize with that idea, but there is complex logic behind the app and walking through all possible branches & ensuring timeouts is simply not an option; I think there has to be something that can limit the time server can spend processing single request ....

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar I can understand you and don't want to be mean but It is design time problem.  And you seek a simple way to solve it which should have been handled previously. Maybe you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13839108/5149474

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually "older" web server solutions - i.e. IIS are using one-thread-per-request separation and `ThreadAbortException` to kill slow requests. Owin is using different philosophy - i.e. it fires new task per request and forcibly cancelling task is best avoided. There are two sides of this problem:

- shus client away if it takes too long
- cancel server processing if it takes too long

Both can be achieved using middleware component. There also is a cancellation token provided directly by owin infrastructure for cases when client disconnects (`context.Request.CallCancelled` where `context` is `IOwinContext`)

If you're interested only in cancelling server flow ASAP when it takes to long, I'd recommend something like

```
public class MyMiddlewareClass : OwinMiddleware
{
    // 5 secs is ok for testing, you might want to increase this
    const int WAIT_MAX_MS = 5000;

    public MyMiddlewareClass(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        using (var source = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(
            context.Request.CallCancelled))
        {
            source.CancelAfter(WAIT_MAX_MS);
            // combined "client disconnected" and "it takes too long" token
            context.Set("RequestTerminated", source.Token);
            await Next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

And then in controller

```
public async Task<string> Get()
{
  var context = this.Request.GetOwinContext();
  var token = context.Get<CancellationToken>("RequestTerminated");
  // simulate long async call
  await Task.Delay(10000, token);
  token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

  return "Hello !";
}
```

Shusing the client away is more complex. The middleware will look like this:

```
public static async Task ShutDownClientWhenItTakesTooLong(IOwinContext context, 
    CancellationToken timeoutToken)
{
    await Task.Delay(WAIT_MAX_MS, timeoutToken);
    if (timeoutToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return;
    }

    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable;
}

public async Task ExecuteMainRequest(IOwinContext context, 
    CancellationTokenSource timeoutSource, Task timeoutTask)
{
    try
    {
       await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
    finally
    {
       timeoutSource.Cancel();
       await timeoutTask;
    }
}

public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
    using (var source = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(
        context.Request.CallCancelled))
    using (var timeoutSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        source.CancelAfter(WAIT_MAX_MS);
        context.Set("RequestTerminated", source.Token);
        var timeoutTask = ShutDownClientWhenItTakesTooLong(context, timeoutSource.Token);
        await Task.WhenAny(
            timeoutTask,
            ExecuteMainRequest(context, timeoutSource, timeoutTask)
        );
    }
}
```